# How can i display random sums

Tags: android

i want to display a set of random questions when the user presses keypad_hash

Comment: Take a look at the class "Random". Combined with an ArrayList containing your questions you nearly got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of questions:

```
List<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("6 + 7 = ??");
    add("8 + 9 = ??");
    add("11 - 3 = ??");
}}
```

Then, just pick a random index between 0 and the length of the array - 1:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
String randomQuestion = questions.get(
    rnd.nextInt(questions.length)
);
```

*P.S. The credit for the line `rnd.nextInt(questions.length)` goes to @WarrenFaith. I was using an extremely stupid way of doing it [`(int)(rnd.nextFloat()*(questions.length-1))`]*

Instead of strings you may want to use a class like:

```
class Question {
    String questionString;
    int answer;

    // .. Definitions and declarations
}
```

I'll leave that upto you as an excercise :)

Comment: `(int)(rnd.nextFloat()*(questions.length-1))` Wait what? How about the much much much easier: `rnd.nextInt(questions.length)`?

Comment: @WarrenFaith: I am currently in the process of thinking of a good excuse :(